# Add average line to scatter graph

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-charts-trendlines

I have the following scatter plot in Google Sheets and I would like to add a line that averages all my points.

[image: Plot example]

Can I do that and if yes, how?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does it answer your question? If no, can please give me some feedback on how to answer your question more properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, calculate the linear regression factors: y=ax+b with the following formula:

```
=LINEST(B2:B21;A2:A21)
```

Then add another column next to the y-axis and name it calculated y-axis. Build the following formula to calc. the y-axis and copy that for all x-values.:

```
=$D$3*A2+$E$3
```

Next is a piece of cake. Add the calculated y-axis to the existing data range or add it seperately.

**UPDATE**: I've added the calculated mean value as well, in order to be absolutely sure to have answered your question properly, see plot:
[image: Plot with mean and linear regression]

See example file for more details: [plot regression example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdF9vMExqTnRLN09zVVFDdVc3VzVuYWc)